# Transparent streaks/lines appearing in cropped images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas, ng-img-crop

There are some transparent streaks/lines appeared in the cropped image by ngngImgCrop.

However it happens randomly and I could not consistently re-produce it.

The images mostly fine but sometimes the uploaded images could have some random lines in the background as following .
[image]

Has anyone ever seen similar issue? any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: no, I don't think converting dataURI is the issue but I just list the code as a reference.

Comment: Then you would be better to [edit] your question and remove this part since it is unrelatted and just makes some noise for readers. Now the problem is certainly due to some roundings made in your cropper, that I don't know. You may want to add the angularjs tag to your question to get a larger audience.

Comment: @Kaiido, updated the question. thanks.