# Tiny transparent lines appear in Windows 10 Mail (and web Gmail on mobile) between images

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

(this is probably related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078413/transparent-streaks-lines-appearing-in-cropped-images), but that has no answers)

I work on an email newsletter which exclusively consists of a couple of images (yeah I know it's old, but it's just the way I received these), particularly slices. Placing these underneath each other consistently without spacings is already a torture, but as these finally seemed to look ok, I encounter this in Windows 10 Mail: tiny horizontal lines between these slices, often randomly appearing, and spasming while scrolling, but rarely disappearing.

[image: Tiny transparent lines between these images]

Various queries I entered in the search engine in the quest for a remedy for this terrible feature in Windows 10 Mail and Gmail (only in the mobile web version, which I doubt anybody uses today, but still, that already is a pain in the ass because of its lack of support for media queries, but that's another story) and eventually I ended up with a code like this, though it doesn't resolve it (though in Outlook 2016 it used to appear too, though now, somehow, it seems to be fixed).

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"
    style="width:100%;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top;border:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
        <a href="#">
            <img
                src="[source here]"
                width="100%"
                style="display: block;line-height: 1px;font-size:1px;margin:0px;padding:0px;border:none;width:100%;text-decoration:none;min-width:100%;max-width: 100%;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;"
                alt=""
                align="absbottom">
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This all is repeated and wrapped within a fluid table of normally exactly/minimally/maximally 600px wide, which is being wrapped in a gray-coloured wrapper table. There are some reset styles within a  in the , the ones everybody use already I suppose. I have even tried wrapping the images in another table, but the issue persists.

Do you appear to have seen this particular issue as well? Are there some suggestions one could try, not included in the embedded code? And, more fundamentally maybe, am I overcomplicating a mail like this? Could this be an issue with the fact my Windows is standard on 125% zoom, and/or is this a DPI related issue?